# JSF custom UISelectOne POSTback error ; Validation Error: Value is not valid

Tags: jsf-2

I have problem in Custom UISelectOne component . My purpose is  creating new custom component which containes own data . So I've creatit dummy data access in component's costactor method as shown below.  When I put the control in XHTML file  , It works correcty on page first load but when I click to  subbmit button of HTML page the error and a warning occurs. Error and Warning messages are like  below;

By the way I have seen some similar questionsins . But none of them was about custom control and I couldn't solve my problem. As As I said I want to load data in components own contractor. So I think my situation seems like different.

> ) WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been
>   displayed. sourceId=j_idt6:j_idt7[severity=(ERROR 2),
>   summary=(j_idt6:j_idt7: Validation Error: Value is not valid),
>   detail=(j_idt6:j_idt7: Validation Error: Value is not valid)]

So My Control and formater codes  :

```
@Named("ABankAccountList")
@RequestScoped
@FacesComponent(createTag = true, namespace = "http://abank.com.tr/example", tagName = "ABankAccountList", value = "com.abank.customcontrols.ABankAccountList")
public class ABankAccountList extends UISelectOne {



    private List<Account> accounts;

    public ABankAccountList() {

       this.setConverter(new AccountConverter());
        accounts=new ArrayList<Account>();
        Account tempAcc = null;
        for (int i = 5; i < 8; i++) {
            tempAcc = new Account();
            tempAcc.setAccountId(i);
            tempAcc.setAccountNumber(i + "0456-789");
            tempAcc.setCurrencyCode("TRY");
            tempAcc.setIbanNumber("TR-" + i + "-98583213213223");
            accounts.add(tempAcc);

        }

    }   

    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }

    public void setAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }

    // After POST Back
    @Override
    public void decode(FacesContext context) {


        super.decode(context);


    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {

        if (context.isPostback()) 
        {
            return ;

        }

        UISelectItems selectItems = new UISelectItems();

        List<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        try {

            for (Account account : accounts) {
                SelectItem item = new SelectItem(account, account.getAccountNumber());
                result.add(item);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log.error("Failed to create enum list", e);
        }


        getChildren().clear();

        selectItems.setValue(result);
        getChildren().add(selectItems);






    }

    // Render HTML
    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException {


        super.encodeEnd(context);
    }



}
```

Also I have a Convertet class as below . **And when I debug the code I notice that getAsObject method fires two times after postbak.  I'm not sure is it normal or not ?**

```
@FacesConverter(value = "AccountConverter")
public class AccountConverter implements Converter
{

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent uiComponent, String arg2) 
    {

         ValueExpression vex = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()  .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(),       
                 "#{ABankAccountList}", ABankAccountList.class);

         ABankAccountList contoller = (ABankAccountList)vex.getValue(context.getELContext());
         Account rAccount=null;
         for (Account acc : contoller.getAccounts()) {
                if (arg2.toString().equals(acc.getAccountId().toString())) {
                    rAccount = acc;
                }
            }        

            return rAccount;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object account) {
         Account accctemp=((Account)account);
         Integer accid=accctemp.getAccountId();
         return accid.toString();

    }

}
```

Actually I am not sure about where should I load Data and whreer should set Converter class.  whatI understand is ; problem is because of data matching before and after postback.  But I have no idea what should I do ?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution.   I've override the equals method of Value Class .

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj instanceof Account) 
        {
            Account other = (Account) obj;
            if (other.getAccountId() == this.getAccountId()
                && other.getIbanNumber() == this.getIbanNumber()    
                    )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```